# Mostrar los datos de una matriz de la siguiente forma:

Tags: python, bucle-for, numpy, matriz

Cree una matriz aleatoria de 32x32 y extraiga bloques contiguos de 3x3 empezando desde
la posición 0,0 (primer bloque 0,0 - 2,2 – segundo bloque 3,3 - 5,5 y así sucesivamente )

La primera matriz tiene las posiciones

[0,0] [0,1] [0,2]

[1,0] [1,1] [1,2]

[2,0] [2,1] [2,2]

Así quedaria la primera matriz de 3x3

La segunda matriz 3x3 quedaria así

Desde las posiciones

[3,3] [3,4] [3,5]

[4,3] [4,4] [4,5]

[5,3] [5,4] [5,5]

ETC

He intentado varias horas que me quede así pero no se bien como recorrerlas.

```
import numpy as np
matriz = np.arange(1,1025).reshape((32,32))

for i in range(1024):
  print(matriz[i][j])
  for j in range (1024):
    print(matriz[i][j])
    i=i+1
    j=j+1
```

Este es el codigo que he intentado hacer pero no me funciona

Comment: Buen día, creo entender la idea, ¿Quieres dividir una matriz en bloques de 3x3, cierto? Creo que las coordenadas de tu segunda matriz están mal en la pregunta, pero ignorando eso, una matriz de 32x32 no puede dividirse en bloques de 3x3, los bloques que estén cerca de los bordes de la matriz no tendrían valores suficientes para hacerlo, tendría que ser de 33x33. o ¿Cómo esperas resolver el problema que la matriz no sea divisible por el tamaño de los bloques?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Buen día,

Podrías utilizar una combinación de [`numpy.reshape`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.reshape.html) con [`numpy.swapaxes`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.swapaxes.html) para crear los bloques, pero hay otro problema, como puse en el comentario, hay casos que la matriz (M, N) no sea divisible en el tamaño de bloques (m, n) configurado.

Un ejemplo sería, teniendo una matriz de 4 por 4, al intentar separarla en bloques de 2 por 2 no habría problemas, pero al intentar separarla en bloques de 3 por 3 únicamente podríamos hacer el primer bloque porque no hay elementos suficientes. Otra opción que creo sería mejor, es agregar filas y columnas con un valor determinado que pueda ser elegido por el usuario.

Hice una función que realiza lo comentado anteriormente

Los métodos [`numpy.r_`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.r_.html) y [`numpy.c_`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.c_.html) se utilizan para concatenar filas (Rows) y columnas respectivamente.

Los bloques se crean de izquierda a derecha y de arriba hacia abajo

```
import numpy as np

def bloques(matriz, nrows, ncols, filler):
    #Dividir una matriz en sub matrizes

    r, h = matriz.shape
    
    #Validar si la matriz es divisible por el número de filas y columnas
    #En caso contrario agregar filas y/o columnas según sea necesario
    while h % nrows != 0:
        # Agregar columnas utilizando "filler" para cada nuevo elemento
        matriz = np.c_[matriz, np.full(r, filler)]
        r, h = matriz.shape
    
    while r % ncols != 0:
        #Agregar filas utilizando "filler" para cada nuevo elemento
        matriz = np.r_[matriz, [np.full(h, filler)]]
        r, h = matriz.shape
    
    # Regresar los bloques de tamaño [nrows, ncols]
    return (matriz.reshape(h//nrows, nrows, -1, ncols)
                 .swapaxes(1, 2)
                 .reshape(-1, nrows, ncols))

matriz = np.random.rand(4,4)
print(matriz)
b = bloques(matriz, 3, 3, 0)
for i in b:
    print(i)
```

Utilizando una matriz de ejemplo de 4 por 4

```
[[0.52415764 0.40264294 0.05015354 0.18056611]
 [0.22324492 0.76061367 0.83139778 0.71840166]
 [0.64091326 0.89751854 0.4006832  0.22911819]
 [0.38059384 0.12351579 0.72566029 0.34900971]]
```

Obtenemos los siguientes 4 bloques de 3 por 3

```
#Bloque 1
[[0.52415764 0.40264294 0.05015354]
 [0.22324492 0.76061367 0.83139778]
 [0.64091326 0.89751854 0.4006832 ]]

#Bloque 2
[[0.18056611 0.         0.        ]
 [0.71840166 0.         0.        ]
 [0.22911819 0.         0.        ]]

#Bloque 3
[[0.38059384 0.12351579 0.72566029]
 [0.         0.         0.        ]
 [0.         0.         0.        ]]

#Bloque 4
[[0.34900971 0.         0.        ]
 [0.         0.         0.        ]
 [0.         0.         0.        ]]
```

Comment: Lo probé también con tu matriz de 32 por 32 y funciona correctamente, pero sería muy largo si pongo el resultado en la respuesta